# How can I handle NavigationView back icon click in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I implemented NavigationView inside MainActivity. MainActivity contains Fragment container .By default HomeFragment is inside this container. Then I add another Fragment(SecondFragment) in this container. Now the hamburger icon should be changed to back navigation icon (back arrow icon) ,clicking on this should go to previous fragment.But now clicking on home button(back arrow icon) opens Navigation Drawer. This is my MainActivity`
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);


    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();


            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {




                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

            }
        }
    });


    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {


            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {

        return false;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

`

And This is my SecondFragment code `
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView inbox;

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        Log.e("backIcon", "backIcon");
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

`

Comment: to go back to previous fragment .....in(if == R.id.home) call onBackPressed() method and return true ;

Comment: Log itself is not getting printed.Instead Navigation Drawer opens

Comment: I think **onOpitonItemSelected()** method of main activity must be called when you click your home button  , not the one in second fragment . You can try that by putting a **Log** there also

Answer (score 0):

You can handle with KeyCode:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                // handle back button

                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

OR

You need to fetch id of onOptionsItemSelected item.
So according to that you can decide back press.